# ERROR: identifier "CvBGCodeBookModel" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm using hand gesture recognizer. So, I referred below links for recognizing hand:

- http://anikettatipamula.blogspot.ro/2012/02/hand-gesture-using-opencv.html
- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7lDtwez94H3Z1JZLXVuOFM2emM/edit?pli=1

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: identifier "CvBGCodeBookModel" is undefined
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"       // Mat is defined here.
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
//VARIABLES for CODEBOOK METHOD: 
CvBGCodeBookModel* model = 0;

...

model = cvCreateBGCodeBookModel();
cvCvtColor( rawImage, yuvImage, CV_BGR2YCrCb );//YUV For codebook method
cvBGCodeBookClearStale( model, model->t/2 );
```

Comment: both blog links above use the outdated c-api. you want to avoid their code

Comment: CvBGCodeBookModel was moved to legacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading between your lines, i guess, that you wanted to do some background separation.

just avoid the outdated CvBGCodeBookModel (as well as the whole arcane c-api) and use one of the

c++ backgruondsubtractors, e.g [backgroundsubtractormog2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2) .

here's [sample code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/cpp)

Comment: ok. I need to run this code https://github.com/bengal/opencv-hand-detection. how to do?

Comment: there are probably 10000000 blogposts about hand detection out there. just avoid anything using iplimages

Comment: Can you suggest me an one blogpost?

Comment: no, i never read those. but your main problem is still, that you're looking for something readymade to steal. instead, read alot, and try to grasp the concept behind it.